# Java multiple replace on a single pass

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to translate nodes on a newick formatted tree, and I'm having trouble getting the replacing right. Say I have the `HashMap`:

```
"(1:" : "(30:"
",1:" : ",30:" 
"(30:" : "(6:"
",30:" : ",6:"
```

And the tree:

```
(30:0.07,(1:0.06,2:0.76))
```

Conventional wisdom would suggest multiple `replaceAll`, but this poses a problem:

```
replaceAll("(1:", "(30:") >> (30:0.07,(30:0.06,2:0.76))
replaceAll("(30:", "(6:") >> (6:0.07,(6:0.06,2:0.76))
```

The problem here is we've replaced a node that was previously replaced. The correct tree should look like:

```
(6:0.07,(30:0.06,2:0.76))
```

Now I've already done this in Python:

```
def multiple_replace(taxa, text): 
    regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, taxa.keys())))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: taxa[mo.group(0)], text)
```

But I'm having trouble with my Java implementation:

```
private String convertTree (String treeOld, HashMap<String, String> conv) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+:|,\\d+:");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(treeOld);
        StringBuilder sbt = new StringBuilder(treeOld);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replace = conv.get(matcher.group());
            System.out.println(matcher.group() + "||" +replace + " || " + matcher.start() + ":"+matcher.end());
            sbt.delete(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
            sbt.insert(matcher.start(), replace);
        }
        return treeOld;

    }
```

While the replacing appears to work, I can't get the indexing quite correct with different sizes of strings (as shown in the example). Is there a way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) to modify your string while matching.

Note that your regex can be simplified to `[,(]\d+:` as your alternative branches only differ in the first character (`[,(]` matches either `,` or `(`).

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/4sa0cj):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String tree = "(30:0.07,(1:0.06,2:0.76))";
        HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
        h.put("(1:" , "(30:");
        h.put(",1:" , ",30:");
        h.put("(30:" , "(6:");
        h.put(",30:" , ",6:");
        System.out.println(convertTree(tree, h));

    }
    private static String convertTree(String treeOld, HashMap<String, String> conv) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,(]\\d+:");  // Init the regex
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(treeOld);            // Init the matcher
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();        // Declare the string buffer (can be replaced with a string builder)
        while (m.find()) {                               // Iterate through matches
            if (conv.containsKey(m.group(0))) {          // Check if the key exists
                m.appendReplacement(result, conv.get(m.group(0))); // If yes, use the HashMap value
            }
            else {
                m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(0));  // Else, just reinsert the match value
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(result);        // Append what remains to the result
        return result.toString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out, needed to use an offset value:

```
private String singlePassConvert (String text, HashMap<String, String> conv) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+:|,\\d+:");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int offset = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replace = conv.get(matcher.group());
            String head = (String) text.subSequence(0, matcher.start() + offset);
            String tail = (String) text.subSequence(matcher.end() + offset, text.length());

            text = head + conv.get(matcher.group()) + tail;

            if (matcher.group().length() > conv.get(matcher.group()).length()) {
                offset --;
            } else if (matcher.group().length() < conv.get(matcher.group()).length()) {
                offset ++;
            }
        }
        return text;

}
```

However, fair warning, since this implementation doesn't use `StringBuilder`, it may be slow on large strings.

Additionally, the offset value only works for differences in length of +/- 1, and should be modified if the length differences are not known.

Comment: You solved the problem in 5 mins after posting it and got +5 upvotes for the question and +4 upvotes for the answer? Looks quite fishy.

Comment: @krzyk And why is that? Someone can post a question immediately followed by an answer; It's actually [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but 5 mins after posting? With a new bunch of code? For me it looks not right, and the number of upvotes just adds to that bad feeling.

Comment: @krzyk If you think a question can help other people, and you *have* the answer, you can post them immediately at the same time. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I get that it looks strange @krzyk, but I actually had the question open and ready to post for 30 minutes while I fiddled. I knew I was close to the answer and didn't want to waste peoples time, should have just kept at it a little longer!